# Postcss Advanced Variables could not resolve the mixin media-breakpoint-down error (Laravel / Tailwind)

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, postcss

I have a Laravel application with tailwind / postcss and when npm run dev is executed I get the following error:

```
postcss-advanced-variables: /var/www/html/resources/css/login.css Could not resolve the mixin for "media-breakpoint-down"
```

This is my webpack.mix.js file:

```
const process = require('process')
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
const cssImport = require('postcss-import')
const cssNesting = require('postcss-nesting')
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config')
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix
  .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .vue({ runtimeOnly: (process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production') === 'production' })
  .webpackConfig(webpackConfig)
  .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    // prettier-ignore
    cssImport(),
    require("postcss-advanced-variables"),
    cssNesting(),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require("autoprefixer"),
  ])
  .version()
  .sourceMaps()
```

and webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path')

// https://stefanbauer.me/tips-and-tricks/autocompletion-for-webpack-path-aliases-in-phpstorm-when-using-laravel-mix
module.exports = {
  output: { chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]' },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve('./resources/js'),
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
  },
  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: 'all',
  },
}
```

I have tried searching online but couldn't really find anything to help resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.